# What happens when I die?

Tags: darksiders-2

When I die in Darksiders 2, and I respawn. Does it has any affect on me, like loss of xp, or loss of starting health, or am I returned to the respawn place at the exact same condition in which I died?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returned to the respawn place with a few caveats.

1. Any potions you used between the respawn point and death are restored.
2. Any reaper energy you have accrued, stays accrued.
3. Smaller enemies in the immediate vicinity do not respawn. They stay dead, and you get to keep anything they dropped between their death and yours.

Considering how many times I lost to Argul... I became intimately familiar with these features!

Comment: Except on Nightmare mode.* When you die on nightmare mode it's back to square one :)

Comment: Ugh, I could never play a hardcore mode on a linear game. It's one thing in a roguelike, where the game is never the same, but in a game with the story line it sounds awful.